# KDE Plasma disable startup apps

Tags: kde, autostart

I'd like to disable the kaccessible software, without uninstalling it, so it doesn't show up on startup. Also, konsole also starts automatically on startup without me setting it up to do so. I'd like that gone too. What files do I need to edit to make these things possible? I tried some paths, none useful:

```
~/.kde/share/autostart
/usr/share/autostart/
```

I also tried making a shell script that kills those processes on startup... didn't work out either

Answer (score 3):

Issue with konsole starting at launch was because of a setting. In the "Desktop Session" menu, I had checked the setting "restore previous session" which, apparently always opened konsole. After checking "Start with empty session" issue was solved. Still haven't found a way to disable kaccessible, think I'll just uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

in plasma [kde 4 & 5] you can go to system settings:  in the "workspace" row the first icon should be "desktop behavior"... in there you click on the guy in a wheelchair and the last tab is screen read and you can just uncheck that without uninstalling.

OR you can just "sudo apt-get purge kaccessible"

Comment: I cannot find such a setting... The thing closest to what you mention in the Plasma System Settings is "Workspace Behaviour" under "Workspace". Clicking on that doesn't display any wheelchair icon, not to mention anything that could be of use for disabling startup apps. I want to stop Konqueror and Skype from starting automatically upon login, but don't want to uninstall one of the two. Anything you would change to your answer from 2017?